# Why do relatively positioned elements ignore floated elements

Tags: css

When a static block element follows a floated element it will fill the remaining space available to it.

So, for example `.right` will take a width of 80%:

```
.left {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;    
}

.right {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/yryZR/**

However, when a block element with `position: relative` follows a floated element, the floated element seems to be ignored and the relative element takes 100% width:

```
.left {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;    
}

.right {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/yryZR/1/**

According to the W3C *"Once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow or floated, it may be shifted relative to this position" [(source)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning)*

So if I am not changing the `left` or `right` positions of the element, why does it set itself to the very left of its parent element rather than stay in the normal flow?

Comment: "why does it set itself to the very left of its parent element rather than stay in the normal flow?" **That's your answer**.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that is a fair point, I will change the title to better reflect what my question actually is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position:relative` refers to the position the element would've been in had there been no CSS positioning overrides - e.g. its natural unaltered position.

floated elements are essentially removed from document positioning calculations, so your `left` element is invisible for the `right` element's positioning, so it takes the size of the next higher element - the container that these two left/right boxes are in.

Comment: +1 thanks, the reason for this is explained in more detail in [W3C - Block Formatting](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)